# vector angular offset

Tags: math

Lets say I have 2 points - A and B. Between them and 0,0 forms an angle, I want to move point A so that point B moves too preserving the angle between them.

Right now I convert the vector offset into radians, add the angle I need and convert back to normal vector which I then use to place B in the right place. I was wondering though, if I can optimize this process by avoiding the jump to angles and back? Since sine functions are computationally expensive on a CPU this could provide a great speedup.

Comment: Which angle is to be preserved? The angle at (0, 0) made by A and B?

Comment: Then the position of B is not unique. Suppose the origin is O, then you can put B anywhere on the ray OB, keeping A constant. For any position of A, there is infinitely many possible positions for B preserving the angle at O.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that. What i need is the ray OB in the form of a normalized vector

Comment: How is the movement of A defined; translation by a vector (x,y) or what?

Answer (score 0):

Normalize both the vectors to `vec(a)`, `vec(b)`. Assuming the angle between the vectors is `ang(p)`, keep a transformation matrix of `A=[cosp,-sinp;sinp, cosp]` (this need not be calculated again and again as it is constant), as the angle between them does not change transform the rotated unit vector `vec(a1)` with matrix `A` to get unit vector `vec(b1)`, then undo the normalisation to get real value. If many points exist, matrices for all these angles will have to be kept.